# How to get twitteR PIN code during R oauth authentication?

Tags: r, twitter, oauth

I’m trying to use the twitteR package .

I use this code to register my credentials:

```
requestURL <-  "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"  
accessURL =    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"  
authURL =      "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"  
consumerKey =   "------------"  
consumerSecret = "-----------"  
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,  
                         consumerSecret=consumerSecret,  
                         requestURL=requestURL,  
                         accessURL=accessURL,  
                         authURL=authURL)

download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",  
          destfile="cacert.pem")  

twitCred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")
```

I then get the link to twitter:
To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=xxxx

but it returns an "Error 403" page.

So I try to edit the URL to https:// instead of http://, I follow the link and within the twitter page, 
and then click on the “Authorize app” button.This sends me back to the site I listed as the callback URL. 
I don’t see the PIN number I was expecting anywhere.

Hoping somebody could help me.

Comment: @MarkeD It sends me back to the site again when I click on the “Authorize app” button.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the https, see if this code works as it does for me:

```
### 1. Register your Twitter app here https://apps.twitter.com/app/new
### 2. Get your api_key and api_secret, fill in below
### 3. Source this file, copy the Twitter Authentication URL
### 4. Input the PIN every session you need access to Twitter API

require(twitteR)

api_key    = "XXXXX"
api_secret = "XXXXX"

TwitterOAuth<-function(){
  reqURL   <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
  accessURL<- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
  authURL  <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
  twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=api_key,
                               consumerSecret=api_secret,
                               requestURL=reqURL,
                               accessURL=accessURL,
                               authURL=authURL)

  options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", 
                              "cacert.pem", 
                              package = "RCurl")))

  twitCred$handshake()

  registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
}

TwitterOAuth()
```

I did a post on it [here](http://markedmondson.me/how-to-use-r-to-analyse-and-plot-your-twitter-use).

Comment: @Kate R. I can't comment on the question as not enough rep, but have you done the registration of the app? https://apps.twitter.com/app/new  I just confirmed the above works with a new api_key and secret.  Are they copied down correctly?  I get redirected to here: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize